# Were the original forms of the Great Race of Yith ever explored?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, cthulhu-mythos, the-shadow-out-of-time

In H. P. Lovecraft's [*The Shadow Out of Time*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Shadow_Out_of_Time), we learn that the four-limbed rugose bodies of the Great Race of Yith are not their original forms:

> And, meanwhile, the Great Race itself waxed well-nigh omniscient....It sought likewise to fathom the past years and origin of that black, aeon-dead orb in far space whence its own mental heritage had come—for the mind of the Great Race was older than its bodily form.
>
> The beings of a dying elder world, wise with the ultimate secrets, had looked ahead for a new world and species wherein they might have long life; and had sent their minds en masse into that future race best adapted to house them—the cone-shaped beings that peopled our earth a billion years ago.

We later find out that an *in-world* document describes the original Yithian homeworld, though perhaps not to the level of detail or accuracy hoped for:

> Thus it was when the minds of the Great Race sped across the void from that obscure, trans-galactic world known in the disturbing and debatable Eltdown Shards as Yith.

Did Lovecraft, or any other Mythos writer, ever describe the origins of the Great Race of Yith in more detail, either by describing the contents of the *Eltdown Shards* in more detail or otherwise?

Comment: Lovecraft did not say much more about the Great Race's past than is in "The Shadow Out of Time," but some other author probably did, perhaps in *The Yith Cycle: Tales of the Great Race*.